# How to show something does not vary with time?

Tags: analysis, physics, mathematical-physics, applications, fixed-points

> Consider a glider flying at velocity $\bf u$ (giving $u = |\bf u| $ on its speedometer) at an angle $θ ∈ (−π, π]$ to the horizon.
>   Positive angle $θ ∈ (0, π/2)$ coincides with the glider’s nose tilted upwards relative to the horizon, whereas for
>   $θ ∈ (−π, −π/2) ∪ (π/2, π)$ the plane is upside down. Its trajectory is governed approximately by the dynamical
>   system
>   $$\dot{u} = − \sin θ − bu^2$$
>   $$u \dot{θ} = − \cos θ + u^2$$
>   Here, the trigonometric terms are due to gravity whereas the quadratic terms result from the hydrodynamic
>   drag and lift experienced by the glider. The control parameter b is the drag coefficient.
>
> Zero drag ($b = 0$):
>
> $(a)$ For the special (ideal) case of zero drag, show that $3u \cos θ − u
> ^3$ does not vary with time, $t$. Hence,
>   explain why this system is conservative.
>
> $(b)$ Calculate the fixed points and using the result in $(a)$ only, determine the phase portrait in the immediate
>   vicinity of the fixed points. Do not conduct a linear stability analysis. Hint: A Taylor expansion may help.
>
> $(c)$ Find the curves corresponding to where the quantity in $(a)$ vanishes.

Hello everyone. I'm struggling to understand this question. Where does the result "$3u \cos θ − u^3$" come from? Also how would you show that it does not vary with time? Should I be solving the differential equations? I don't know how to attempt this question, mainly because I can't see the relevance of "$3u \cos θ − u^3$" to this question. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Does not vary with time" = "Constant with respect to time" = "The derivative with respect to $t$ is $0$"

So, show that $\dfrac d{dt} (3u \cos\theta - u^3) = 0$.

I'm not sure where the expression comes from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $b=0$ we have the system
\begin{align}
\dot{u} &= -\sin(\theta) \\
u \dot{\theta} &= -\cos(\theta) + u^2
\end{align}
We now check the time derivative of the given term
\begin{align}
(d/dt) (3u\cos(\theta)-u^3) 
&= 3 \dot{u} \cos(\theta) - 3u\sin(\theta)\dot{\theta} -3u^2 \dot{u} \\
&= 3 (\underbrace{-\sin(\theta)}_{\dot{u}})\cos(\theta) 
-3 (\underbrace{-\cos(\theta) + u^2}_{u\dot{\theta}})\sin(\theta) - 3 u^2 (-\sin(\theta)) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you a lot for a very clear and well-explained answer.

Comment: @RyanJ  My guess is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics) . It could also be some sort of energy, but I did not spot a Lagrangian for that yet. I can look into this only later today.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I've found out why in my notes. Thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: @RyanJ You sparked my curiosity. What did your notes say?

Comment: It says "A system is said to be conservative if there exists a nonconstant real-valued continous function, $E(x)$, that is constant on trajectories, ie $\frac{dE}{dt} = 0$". That function in $(a)$ satisfies this I believe (for a 2d dynamical system).

Comment: This might be a silly question, but would you consider $u$ as the independent variable in this question?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by independent variable. The system varies with time $t$. $u$ and $\theta$ are generalized coordinates from the view point of the Lagrange function.